GAM model with multidimensional categorical response variable (with mgcv)
I try to fit a GAM model with a multidimensional categorical response variable combining three binomial dimensions (e.g., A-B by a-b by α-β) lacking certain combinations and depending on a smooth of longitude and latitude by employing the package mgcv. Is there a distribution family or syntax that allows to model the effect of predictor variables on the individual dimensions of the response variable in a single model or do I have to model each dimension separately?
sample data
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(response.dim1 = sample(c("A", "B"), 1000, replace=TRUE),
                 response.dim2 = sample(c("a", "b"), 1000, replace=TRUE),
                 response.dim3 = sample(c("", "α", "β"), 1000, replace=TRUE),
                 longitude = runif(1000, min = 0, max = 100),
                 latitude = runif(1000, min = 50, max = 150))

df$response.comb <- paste(df$response.dim1, df$response.dim2, df$response.dim3, sep = "")

df <- df %>%
  filter(response.comb %in% c("Aa", "Abα", "Abβ", "Bbα", "Bbβ"))

I want a working model along the lines of gam(response.dim1 * response.dim2+3 ~ s(longitude, latitude).
Or is there a way to compute the interactions of response dimension 1 and 2 with gam(response.comb ~ s(longitude, latitude)?

There is a way to do this with mgcv but the syntax is, in my opinion, difficult and confusing. If you are open to Bayesian methods, you can do this with the brms package.

Thanks for the tip! But I don't think that brms can handle non-linear models (like GAMs).

Yes, it definitely can. There is a wrapper for the mgcv function s() implemented in brms. You should have no problem with a multinomial GAM in brms, I have fit them before using that package.

Oh, that's great! Do you happen to know what the syntax for a binomial response, a multinomial response, a parametric fixed effect, a smooth fixed effect and a random effect would be?

I'll try to write that up as an answer if I have time later today.

Thank you so much for your detailed aswer! In my case, however, the single response variable is cateogorical, but not ordinal: the 5 levels are, let's say, Aa, Abα, Abβ, Bbα, Bbβ. They could be thought of as combining a binomial dimension A-B and a multionomial dimension a-bα-bβ (with a-b and α-β being binomial again). Can brms handle this kind of structure (including gam-smooths)?

Yes, you just have to specify the categorical response family instead of multinomial. In the future if you are changing the question significantly, it's better to ask a new question instead of editing the question so that the answer someone provided doesn't match the question anymore.

Here is a fairly basic way to fit a binomial and multinomial generalized additive mixed model (GAMM) using the R package brms.
Simulate data
First, simulate some data with three response classes. Response class 2 always has the same probability, 0.1. Response class 1 has a probability depending on the sine of time, plus a random effect and a fixed effect. Response class 3 probability is 1 - the sum of p1 and p2.
We have to encode the responses as numerical columns, one for each category, with the number of outcomes for that category. I simulated it so that there are 10 trials for each combination of fixed and random effects at each time point.
set.seed(1)

library(brms)

# Simulate some data, assume sinusoidal pattern with time, a random effect due to block, and fixed effect of treatment
sim_data <- expand.grid(t = 1:10, block = factor(letters[1:5]), treatment = factor(c('control', 'treated')))
p1 <- plogis(sin(sim_data$t) + c(-2, -1.5, -1, -.5, 0)[as.numeric(sim_data$block)] + 0.5*as.numeric(sim_data$treatment))
probs <- cbind(p1, 0.1, 1 - p1 - 0.1)

categories <- t(apply(probs, 1, function(ps) rmultinom(1, 10, ps)))
categories <- cbind(categories, rowSums(categories))
dimnames(categories)[[2]] <- c('animal', 'vegetable', 'mineral', 'n_trials')

sim_data <- cbind(sim_data, categories)

Multinomial GLMM
Next, we fit a multinomial model. The syntax for the response part of the formula is cbind(<names of the response categories>) | trials(<name of the column with the number of trials>). The syntax for the fixed and random effects is similar to lme4 syntax, and the smooth term uses the same arguments as mgcv::s(). Note: I specified a thin-plate spline, bs = 'tp' with basis dimension k = 5, but you should read about the options and carefully decide what is appropriate for you.
The family argument tells brm() that we are modeling a multinomially distributed response with a (generalized) logit link, and we can also specify which category is the reference category.
If your response is categorical but not ordinal, you may use family = categorical(link = 'logit') instead of family = multinomial(link = 'logit'). That will perform softmax regression.
Note also that I did not change any defaults for prior distributions, sampling iterations, or anything like that. You should definitely not blindly accept those defaults! A discussion of that is outside the scope of this answer but there is ample material online about it.
Here's the code:
multinom_fit <- brm(cbind(animal, vegetable, mineral) | trials(n_trials) ~ treatment + s(t, k = 5, bs = 'tp') + (1 | block),
                    family = multinomial(link = 'logit', refcat = 'animal'),
                    data = sim_data)

We can call conditional_effects(multinom_fit, categorical = TRUE) to get a quick look at the model predictions for each fixed effect. There are other diagnostics you should run, again a discussion of them is outside the scope of this answer!
It looks like the model is doing a good job of capturing the fixed effect and the sinusoidal time effect on the probabilities of response class 1 (animal) and 3 (mineral) with a close to zero fixed effect time effect on the probability of response class 2 (vegetable), as we simulated!


Binomial GLMM
We can use the same simulated data to demonstrate the syntax. I won't go through any output but we get similar inference from just modeling the probability of one of the three response classes. The syntax of the response is just <response column name> | trials(<trial column name>) and we specify family = binomial(link = 'logit').
binom_fit <- brm(animal | trials(n_trials) ~ treatment + s(t, k = 5, bs = 'tp') + (1 | block),
                 family = binomial(link = 'logit'),
                 data = sim_data)

